# Custom HTML5 Mp3 Player

Tags: javascript, html, custom-controls, html5-audio

I need this in full functionality but I seem to of forgotten how to connect multiple JavaScript files into one function. 
Here's my Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
<script type="text/javascript"
source src="/storage/
emulated/0/Documents/
Mp3Player/js/
MyScript.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
source src="/storage/
emulated/0/Documents/
Mp3Player/js/MyScript1.js"></
script>
</head> 
<body> 
<img src="/storage/emulated/0/
Documents/Mp3Player/html/
images/play.jpg" width="200" 
height="200" onclick="play(); 
changeImage();"> 
<audio id="audio" src="/storage/
emulated/0/Documents/
Mp3Player/html/music/
Rap_In_Darkness.mp3 "/>
</body> 
</html>
```

Here's MyScript.js for audio playing.

```
function play(){ var myAudio = 
document.getElementById 
("audio"); if(myAudio.paused) 
myAudio.play(); else 
myAudio.pause(); }
```

Here's MyScript1.js for pause/play button images.

```
function changeImage() { if 
(document.getElementById
("imgClickAndChange").src == "/
storage/emulated/0/
Documents/Mp3Player/html/
images/Pause.jpg") { 
document.getElementById
("imgClickAndChange").src = "/
storage/emulated/0/
Documents/Mp3Player/html/
images/play.jpg "; } else { 
document.getElementById
("imgClickAndChange").src = "
storage/emulated/0/
Documents/Mp3Player/html/
images/Pause.jpg "; } }
```

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri can you solve this I want to know if you remember how to link multiple .js files to an html without the clutter

Answer (score 1):

Modify your `index.html` like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head> 
<script type="text/javascript"
src="/storage/
emulated/0/Documents/
Mp3Player/js/
MyScript.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="/storage/
emulated/0/Documents/
Mp3Player/js/MyScript1.js"></
script>
</head> 
<body> 
<img src="/storage/emulated/0/
Documents/Mp3Player/html/
images/play.jpg" width="200" 
height="200" onclick="play(); 
changeImage();"> 
<audio id="audio" src="/storage/
emulated/0/Documents/
Mp3Player/html/music/
Rap_In_Darkness.mp3 "/>
</body> 
</html>
```

Then your `MyScript.js` like this

```
function play(){ var myAudio = 
document.getElementById 
("audio"); if(myAudio.paused) 
myAudio.play(); else 
myAudio.pause(); }
```

Finally, your `MyScript1.js` like this

```
function changeImage() { if 
(document.getElementById
("imgClickAndChange").src == "/
storage/emulated/0/
Documents/Mp3Player/html/
images/Pause.jpg") { 
document.getElementById
("imgClickAndChange").src = "/
storage/emulated/0/
Documents/Mp3Player/html/
images/play.jpg "; } else { 
document.getElementById
("imgClickAndChange").src = "
storage/emulated/0/
Documents/Mp3Player/html/
images/Pause.jpg "; } }
```

Comment: I think that broke my code but by that I mean its not working no offense

Comment: Well, what is the error message in console ? @AnonymationTwentyFourSeven

Comment: I found AnWriter so it has 0 error messages but then why aren't the images or audio loading

Comment: I think you should test the code on PC first, then use it on your Android Device @AnonymationTwentyFourSeven

Comment: I found a solution but it involves a different button code, thanks for the great advice.

Comment: @Bondan Sebastian since you solved this puzzle so quickly (+1!), maybe you can help this other stackoverflow where I am stuck in the final bits of the puzzle mate?   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45017887/minimalist-html5-audio-player-select-by-html-elements-instead-of-div-ids/