# HTML5 Audio Player: How to select by HTML elements instead of div ID's?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio, code-cleanup, getelementsbyname

Making an html5 player, I'm moving away "from divs with id's" towards "simple html elements".

**Old Situation** (works)

```
<audio src="track1.mp3" id="audio"></audio>
<controls>
    <play id="play" style="display:none">PLAY</button>
    <pause id="pause" style="display:none">PAUSE</button>
    <div id="progress"><div id="bar"></div></div>
</controls>
```

*Javascript gets elements by divs with an id*

```
var myAudio = document.getElementById('audio');
var play = document.getElementById('play');
var pause = document.getElementById('pause');
... etc
```

---

**Desired Situation** (doesn't work fully)

```
<audio src="track1.mp3"></audio>
<controls>
    <play style="display:none">PLAY</play>
    <pause style="display:none">PAUSE</pause>
    <progress><bar></bar></progress>
</controls>
```

*Updated Javascript, after help of @grateful & @Nathan Montez works **partially***

```
var myAudio = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0];
var play = document.getElementsByTagName('play')[0];
var pause = document.getElementsByTagName('pause')[0];
... etc
```

In the new version the progress bar does not work! What have we overlooked? Thanks!

Comment: Is is intentional that you want <play></button> instead of <play></play>?

Comment: Is there a reason there is a double-quote in the <progress> tag that is not closed/used?

Comment: <progress"><bar></bar></progress>

Comment: <progress"> should be an invalid html tag. That could be why it is having trouble rendering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.getElementsByTagName('audio')` will return an array, even if it only has a length of 1. You need to do this:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0];
```

Comment: It's array-like but not actually an array. Still, @grateful is correct, you have to specify the element in the list.

Comment: Creating custom elements meets the 'no id' requirements and even works on Internet Explorer: https://jsfiddle.net/6vcu26xh/1/

Answer (score 1):

Moving comment to an answer:

Remove the double quote from the  tag.

It is currently `<progress"></progress>`
It should read `<progress></progress>`

Update:

I think that the cause of your problem is that the elements are resolving to `HTMLUnknownElement`s. Because of this, you may need to work with something like [Google Polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org/) to provide the kind of functionality you are looking for. I don't think you can use Unknown Elements directly like this because they don't have the same API that the native HTMLElement objects do.

Comment: Thanks for your sharp eye: your contribution in bug finding has been rewarded by an upvote and incorporated into my jsfiddle in the question (which is now solved)